# Backup to my own web space

Tags: windows-xp, backup

I am looking for an app that will back everything up to my ftp server.  I have a couple of gigs available.

I know I can use Carbonite or something like that, but don't really want yet another monthly bill.

Comment: Does your web hosting provider (I assume here that "web space" means that you have a web hosting account with some web host) allow using account space as backup? All the ones I've used did not, so it's worth checking that first (if you haven't already.)

Comment: They don't care how I use it.

Comment: I currently store on my Web Host a bunch of stuff, I just copy it there manually.  I'd like the process to be automated.

Comment: My host allows me to use it as storage, but if your doing automated backups, you might hit the some limits pretty quickly

Comment: Currently I have a batch file that does this twice a week, so far there have been no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ftp sync program like carbon ftp or aasync

robotask.com/downloads

aasync.com

but i would recommend not using ftp at all.. maybe sftp is available?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "My Network Places" then "Add a network place".  There's a wizard for using an FTP account.  Once that's done, go to "Tools" -> "Map a network drive" (available in any Explorer window, I think).  Choose a drive to map, then Browse to the network place.

That should work.

Once you have the drive mapped, any tool that can backup/copy to a mapped drive should be able to copy stuff to your ftp account.  Maybe even the built-in backup client.

Comment: Your approach was so promising.  However, I can't map a network drive.  The Ok button on the Browse for Folder dialog never lights up.

Comment: Sorry to hear.  I knew the mechanisms were in place for this to work, though I never actually tried it myself.  Very odd that it doesn't, in spite of it letting you take it that far.